# Nvidia 3D stereo with XNA 4.0 ?

Tags: xna, nvidia

I want to create a program that uses Nvidia 3D Vision with XNA 4.0. Is it possible with XNA 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post on the [xbox forums](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/60236.aspx) there are apparently folks who are successfully doing this.

Snipped from the forum post:

`I just got Nvidia 3d Vision to work with both 3.1 and 4.0`